# How to enumerate lines of gzip-archived text file

Tags: c#, file

How can I read first and last lines of a gzip file and get decompressed lines as a result?
File is big, so I don't want to read it all...

Comment: Last line? You will probably have to decompress everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get the first and last bits from a compressed file without decompressing the entire thing. And it doesn't get much easier than using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/):

```
using Ionic.Zlib;
...
string firstLine = null ;
string lastLine = null ;

using ( FileStream input = File.Open( @"c:\foo\bar\bazbat.gz" , FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read , FileShare.Read ) )
using ( GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream( input , CompressionMode.Decompress ) )
using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( gzip ) )
{
  firstLine = lastLine = reader.ReadLine() ;
  while ( null != (lastLine=reader.ReadLine()) )
  {
    // This space intentionally left blank
  }
}
```

---

**Edited To Note:** DotNetZip used to live at Codeplex. Codeplex has been shut down. The old archive is still [available at Codeplex](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). It looks like the code has migrated to Github:

- https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip. Looks to be the original author's repo.
- https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd. This looks to be the currently maintained version. It's also packaged up an available via Nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

---

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it without reading whole file *at one go*, but it still enumerates through every line rather than giving me last line only.

Internal implementation of File.ReadLines does this:

```
using (reader)
{ 
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        yield return line; 
    }
}
```

Adapted to decompress:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ReadCompressedLines(string filePath)
{
    using (var srcStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    using (var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(srcStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
    {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    } 
}
```

and then you can do .First() and .Last() on IEnumerable.